# VirtualHost slows the server down after a while

Tags: php, node.js, apache, proxy, virtualhost

I'm using a Node.js chatting system (Ajaxim.com) so basically I set up an unique node.js server for it. Then I use VirtualHost in my PHP server to access it like:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests On

Timeout 3600
ProxyTimeout 3600

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from .nodeserver.com
</Proxy>

ProxyVia Off

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/qanda
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ec2-user/verisign/bundle.crt
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/verisign/www.phpserver.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/verisign/www.phpserver.com.key
    ServerName www.phpserver.com

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /chat https://phpserver.com:8000
ProxyTimeout 3600
Timeout 3600

   # ErrorLog logs/phpserver.com-error_log
   # CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javas$
```

It was fine when I just started it, but after like 3-4 hours, it becomes incredibly slow. Like I can't even open my website anymore(php side) or it takes 2 mins to load a single page. What should I do?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is somehow related to Apache or to VirtualHost. Did you try without Apache as a front-end?

Comment: @NitzanShaked No but when i disable these proxy virtual host thing, it works fine. I'm afriad it's realted to SSL?

Comment: FIVE years later...did you solve it ?